# Best voting system where there are few voters and seferal candidates?

Tags: voting-theory

I'm looking at a scenario where there are few voters (2-3), and several to many candidates (20-30) where at most there is room for 3 winners.

Approval voting seems like the way to go to avoid tactical voting, but it seems like in this case, you'd wind up with many candidates that "win". If both voters approve of many candidates, or even just a handful of them, there will be many candidates who receive the maximum amount of votes.

What would method would you suggest using in this case? Bonus points for minimizing the number of voting actions.

Comment: Can the voters vote themselves? Can they abstain?

Comment: They cannot vote for themselves or each other, and the candidates cannot vote. Think of it more like voters choosing a selection of policies, of which only one or a few can be enacted. The voters cannot abstain.